# How to change color of view repeating and forever in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, colors, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a custom view on which I want to change the background color forever. The color should be a gradual change.

So like a dark blur > lighter shade of blue > light green > yellow > red etc. These changes need to be smooth.

I am not sure how to even generate the next possible color and also how to make this smooth and infinite without blocking everything.

Comment: Look into animateWithDuration(); a good place to start I think

Answer (score 0):

Use CAAnimationGroup, just like below:

```
CABasicAnimation * darkToBlue = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
darkToBlue.fromValue = (id)([[UIColor darkGrayColor]CGColor]);
darkToBlue.toValue = (id)[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
darkToBlue.duration = 1;
darkToBlue.beginTime = 0;

CABasicAnimation * blueToRed = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
blueToRed.fromValue = (id)([[UIColor blueColor]CGColor]);
blueToRed.toValue =(id)[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
blueToRed.duration = 1;
blueToRed.beginTime = 1;

CABasicAnimation * redToDark = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
redToDark.fromValue = (id)([[UIColor redColor]CGColor]);
redToDark.toValue =(id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor]CGColor];
redToDark.duration = 1;
redToDark.beginTime = 2;

CAAnimationGroup * group = [[CAAnimationGroup alloc]init];
group.animations = @[darkToBlue,blueToRed,redToDark];
group.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
group.duration = 3;
group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"colors"];
```